# Using Semantic UI with asp.net webforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, semantic-ui

I am trying to integrate Semantic UI in my existing Asp.net webforms project.Everything loads well and theres no such error in console.I am trying to use the "ui dropdown"..but cant see the dropdown like in examples.

Here is my references

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="semantic/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

And the asp.net code

```html
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="OfficeDropDown" CssClass="ui dropdown" />
```

Cant see the curvy dropdown like in Semantic UI..What am i doing wrong?Help please.Searched a lot.Couldnt get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it..I forgot to bind the dropdownlist.

```js
$('#officeDropDown')
  .dropdown()
;
```

worked.